# Using pwntools to interact with executable just halts on receive

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, pwntools

I have a c exectuable that I want to exploit.
The output of that file looks like this:

```
$ ./vuln_nostack 
Enter some text:
enteringTEXT
You entered: enteringTEXT
```

You enter some text, and the program spits it back.

I want to run this prorgam (and later exploit it) with python and pwntools.

So far, the functioning part of my pwntools program looks like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import process
from sys import stdout
from pwn import * 
import time


pty = process.PTY

p = process("./vuln_nostack", stdin=pty, stdout=pty)


ss = p.recv()
p.clean()
asstring = ss.decode("utf-8")

print(asstring)
```

This works fine, it gets the first line and then prints it.

What I want to do now is to send a message to the program and then get the final line.

I have tried something along these lines:

```
p.send(b"dong")

p.clean()

print(p.recv())
```

I'm not sure whether or not the send actually ever sends anything, but as soon as I add the `recv` function, the prorgam just hangs and never finishes.

My guess is that the input to the executable is never given properly, and therefore it's still just waiting.

How do I actually get a message delivered to the exectuable so that it can move on and srever me the last line?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `p.sendline()`:

```
p.sendline("payload")
```

This automatically adds a breakline after your bytes.

Moreover, to know whether your exploit is sending/receiving messages to/from the program,  you can use debug context by adding this assignment:

```
context.log_level = 'debug'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a lot more simple than formerly presumed.

I just needed a breakline in the send:

```
p.send("payload \n")
```